Limit of three times differentiable function
The function $f : [0, +∞)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is three times differentiable, and $f(0)=f(2)=0,
f(1)<0$ and $\forall_{x\geq0}~f'''(x) > 0$. Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(x) = +∞$.
I know, that $f''$ is increasing (so it can have max 1 root), then $f'$ also can be always increasing or decreasing and then increasing. Moreover we know it has to have at least one root in $(0,2)$. But if it increases over a certain interval $(c,+\infty)$, then $f$ is growing faster and faster, so its limit in $+\infty$ has to be $+\infty$. Am I right? And how to write it more formal?

Show that $f''$ is positive somewhere and it is increasing and hence either tends to a positive limit or infinity. Apply L'Hospital on $f' (x) /x$ and then again on $f(x) /x$.

Your intuition is right. To formalize it we can use the first order condition for convexity, which states that for a differentiable convex function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$f(x) \geq f(y) + f'(y)(x-y) \qquad \text{ for all } x,y \in I \tag{1}$$
In other words, the above formalizes the statement that convex functions are always greater than their tangents at any point $(y, f(y))$.
Now back to our problem. From $f'''(x)> 0$ we get that $f''(x)$ is strictly increasing. From the mean value theorem, we get a point $x_1 \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x_1)=f(1)$ and another point $x_2\in (1, 2)$ such that $f'(x_2)=-f(1)$. Applying the mean value theorem once again for $f'(x)$ we get a $c\in (x_1, x_2)$ such that
$$f''(c) = \frac{f'(x_2)-f'(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{-2f(1)}{x_2-x_1} > 0$$
From the monotonicity of $f''(x)$ we can conclude that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\geq c$ which implies that $f(x)$ restricted to $[c, \infty)$ is convex.
Finally, applying $(1)$ for any $x \geq c$ and $y=x_2$ we get
$$f(x) \geq f(x_2) + f'(x_2)(x-x_2) = f(x_2)-f(1)(x-x_2) \quad \forall\; x\geq c$$
The RHS diverges to infinity when $x\to \infty$ (since $f(1)<0$) and so $f(x)\to \infty$.
